# How to wrap of the text is failing for 'W' and 'M' character?

Tags: wpf, textblock

I have a wrapped text block in WPF, wraps the text properly for all the characters except for `W` and `M`, when there is a word with full of `W` and `M` (32 characters) newline is created automatically and split into 2 lines like below

```
"This is an example of big letter  WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWMMMMWWWWWWWWWWW failing the wrap "
```

for other alphabets it works fine as:

```
"This is an example of big letter  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACCCCCCCCCCCCCCC failing the wrap "
```

Comment: Please provide us and example, piece of your code first. Regards.

Comment: I just did a test with inputs you gave => no problem. Please provide a piece of code.

Comment: seems your platform is going through m and w dyslexia..